# StompClient Subscribe

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, stomp

Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
public class ProductController {

    @Autowired
    private ProductService productService;


    @SendTo("/topic/all")
    public List<Product> findAll() {
        return productService.findAll();
    }
}
```

WebSocketConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
    registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws").setAllowedOrigins("http://127.0.0.1:5500").withSockJS();
}
```

Js Code

```
function connect() {
    let stompClient = null;
    let socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/ws');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({}, (frame) => {
            stompClient.subscribe('/topic/all',(response) => {
                console.log(JSON.parse(response))
                console.log(true)
            });

        });

}

connect();
```

hello, this is my small project, my main goal in this project is to show all the products in real time, because when a new product is added by the admin, the same product should be visible to the user. I am using debug stompclient.subscribe not wokring Please help me Thanks

Comment: can yo explain what *subscribe not working* means? any error messages?

Comment: I used debug and it doesn't go into subscribe

Comment: Any output in the console? have you tried to switch on debug? https://stomp-js.github.io/stomp-websocket/codo/class/Client.html

Comment: *doesn't go into subscribe* cound like connect does not work

Comment: Web Socket Opened...
stomp.js:9 >>> CONNECT
accept-version:1.2,1.1,1.0
heart-beat:10000,10000

Comment: Connect is working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247409/discussion-between-rtyuttter-and-jens).